# Windows 10 Mail Client Connected to GMail Account Has Ghost Mail in Inbox. How to Remove?

Tags: email, windows-10, gmail, imap, windows-mail

I'm using the Windows 10 Mail client on my laptop to connect via IMAP to my GMail account.  In the course of trying to move an email from the Inbox to another folder, Mail hung up so I tried a couple of times to move the email.

Now I have two email headers in the Inbox folder view that have no body.  When I click on the headers, there is nothing in the body, I just get an infinite loop of waiting dots.  I have repeatedly tried to delete these ghosts both from the main window and from the mail body window.  The delete will appear to work but then the emails will reappear again at a later time.

How can I remove these ghost emails?

Comment: Have you tried to log into gmail an check if the mails appear there? Can you remove them there? If they are not there you may try to recreate the mail client imap profile.

Comment: They are not on the GMail server, @ivanvictorovic.